# How would would I call "getSelectedItemPosition" from the UI thread? Check error message below

Tags: java, android

Error: Method getSelectedItemPosition must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker.

The error starts here (lines 206-217 of the [full code](http://pastebin.com/nTLx1X6i)). Same error for all lines.

```
                    if(categoryFilter.getSelectedItemPosition()==0)
                        rides.add(map);
                    else if(categoryFilter.getSelectedItemPosition()==1){
                        if(job.getString("accept").equals("0"))
                            rides.add(map);
                    }else if(categoryFilter.getSelectedItemPosition()==2){
                        if(job.getString("accept").equals("1"))
                            rides.add(map);
                    }else if(categoryFilter.getSelectedItemPosition()==3){
                        if(job.getString("accept").equals("2"))
                            rides.add(map);
                    }else if(categoryFilter.getSelectedItemPosition()==4){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use runOnUiThread.

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                if (categoryFilter != nul && categoryFilter.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
// your code here
                                            }
                                        });
```